# how to run binary in android without adb shell

Tags: android, adb

when you run a binary in adb shell, if you exit adb, then the process is over too.

So is there a way to run a binary without adb's help?

Comment: copy binary to the apk folder residing into the device, and than directly running the application by clicking the apk file which will ask to install the app.

Comment: my binary is not *.apk, Alex P.'s method works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have busybox installed on your device, then you could use 'busybox nohup [your binary] &' command. This way it will keep running even after you close adb

Comment: thank you, i think it can work. but the busybox on my device has no applet of nohup.

Comment: i try just run: '[my bin] &' in adb shell. it works, not really use busybox. thank you

Comment: I've done this by doing '[my bin] &', but now how do I find the process later and kill it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sh -c "your-binary-or-command" &
```

Then you can exit the adb shell by pressing ctrl+D and it will continue to run.

You can kill it by going back into the adb shell then

```
kill -s KILL <PID>
```